# How to link to ACF Relationship "parent"

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress to be able to relate content with each other. This is the scenario:

• Make a relationship between post type “design” and post type “item”

• On all of the “design” pages, I’d like to show all “items” from all designs.

• When I click on one of these “items”, id like to go to the url of the “design” linked to that specific item.

This is how it looks like right now:

```
 <?php $items = get_field('items'); ?>
 <?php foreach( $items as $item ): ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($item); ?>


                            <?php 


                    $design = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'design',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'items', // name of custom field
                                'value' => '"' . $item->ID. '"',
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            )
                        )
                    ));

                    ?>                      

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $design->ID ); ?>" target="blank">Link to "Design"</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I thought this would get the url of the related post type "Design", but all I get is the url to the current page.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
The ACF Relationship tutorial has an example like this:

```
 $design = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'design',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'items', // name of custom field
                                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exactly "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            )
                        )
                    ));

                    ?>
                    <?php if( $design ): ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $doctors as $doctor ): ?>
```

But instead of get_the_ID(), I first need to get the ID of each item, and then find the Design including that item. What do I need to change from the tutorial code?

Comment: are you getting correct $design->ID ???

Comment: The id's of the "items" are correct, but it doesn't seem to get the id for the "design" at all. So somehow it seem to be something wrong with the $design array. but I can't find what is wrong :/

Comment: did you check in DB  it has meta_key field with items and meta_value with item->id??? for specific design id

Comment: items is the meta_key and in meta_value are all of the related item->id, like 
     a:2:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:2:"36";}. and in the field "post_id" are the ids of the "Design". Still can't understand why it's not working :/

Comment: which is wrong completely.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is completely wrong?l

Comment: its seems like your post type "design" is not storing meta values. Otherwise you will this data in db post_id -> $design->id, meta_key -> items, meta_value -> $item->id.

Comment: I've now updated the original post with an working example. Hope that makes it a bit more clear :) The problem shouldn't be in the database since the ACF plugin has made the tables necessary for me!

Answer (score 1):

You need see...

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

and this for get "childs"
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

for get the id

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58943/convert-post-name-into-post-id

maybe need this

replace get_the_ID by the $post->ID
in this part..
'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',

```
$post = get_page_by_title( 'your-slug', OBJECT, 'your-post-type' );
echo $post->ID;
```

**note**

-Don´t forget update your post